# CF Builder 1: how to add existing project(s) to Navigator

Tags: coldfusion-9

I have a bunch of .cfm pages written and sitting on on remote server: \rem_serv\shared_dir\

How do I show them in Navigator?[image]

Comment: Have you tried this. Window -> Open Perspective -> 'Other' -> Remote System Explorer. File -> New -> Other -> Remote System Explorer (folder) -> Connection (or type Connection into the filter field) Choose FTP from the 'Select Remote System Type' panel

Comment: This is CF Builder 1 and I don't have the same options. I was able to fix it, but still struggling with making Preview in IE work.